# Start Fuseki Server from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, sparql

I originally use jetty server with xstream library to handle my xml-requests. Now i want to use fuseki server to create some sparql endpoint. I don't want to run the fuseki server from the commandline

I downloaded the fuseki libaray, and tried to start the jetty server in it, but it isnot starting. I tried to find the relevant libraries for handling the sparql so i integrate them with my old jetty libraries but i couldn't find them. Any suggestions?

Thanks